# Getting error only in mongoose, not in mongo shell Error: Can't use $or

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a blog collection whose schema is something like below

```js
{
 content:String,
 type:String,
 author:Number
}
```

### Query

```js
    const edit = await Posts.findByIdAndUpdate(
      {
        _id: postId,
        $or: [
          { type: "blog" },
          { author: 123 },
        ],
      },
      {
        $set: {
          content:"...new"
        },
      }
    );
```

On executing this I am getting the below error

```js
Error: Can't use $or
    at ObjectId.SchemaType.castForQuery (/home/rahul/Desktop/projects/components/components-server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1539:13)
    at ObjectId.SchemaType.castForQueryWrapper (/home/rahul/Desktop/projects/components/components-server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1511:22)
    at cast (/home/rahul/Desktop/projects/components/components-server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/cast.js:316:39)
    at model.Query.Query.cast (/home/rahul/Desktop/projects/components/components-server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4963:12)
    at castQuery (/home/rahul/Desktop/projects/components/components-server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4764:18)
    at model.Query.Query._findAndModify (/home/rahul/Desktop/projects/components/components-server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:3707:23)
    at model.Query.<anonymous> (/home/rahul/Desktop/projects/components/components-server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:3267:8)
    at model.Query._wrappedThunk [as _findOneAndUpdate] (/home/rahul/Desktop/projects/components/components-server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/query/wrapThunk.js:27:8)
```

But the same query  is working with CLI mongo shell

```js
db.posts.findOneAndUpdate({_id:ObjectId("postId"),$or:[{type:"blog"},{author:123}]},{$set:{content:"blog78"}})
```

Comment: Simple, you cannot use `$or` wih `findById*`. Your CLI uses `findOne*`

Comment: find by id expect only the id as search criteria [see](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate)

Comment: You must use a valid `ObectId` with `findById*` functions as the first argument.